# validate URL in form http://www.test.com

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, url

I want to validate URL (using java script) to accept only format - http://www.test.com. I'm trying following code, but it accepts test.com and http://www.test.com.com also.

```
var URLReg = new RegExp();
URLReg.compile("^[A-Za-z]+://[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9-_%&\?\/.=]+$");
if (!URLReg.test(form["URL"].value)) {
    alert("You must supply a valid URL.");
    return false;
}
```

what is wrong in this ? :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is `http://www.test.com` valid while `http://test.com` or `http://www.test.com.com` are not? What makes it "more valid" than the others? Would you test accept `http://stackoverflow.com/`?

Comment: to add to what @Joachim said. `www.test.com.com` is a valid url, why do you want to disallow it?

Comment: @KukePHP: i think there is also a sintax error in your code, since you are creating the regex in a string, you forgot the double back slash \\ before the '?' and do you need the back slash before the slash '/'. The last part of your regex: "...[A-Za-z0-9_/\\-\\%\\&\\?\\.\\=]+" Maybe I even aded too many not necessary backslashes now. But just in case. :)

Comment: This is the sort of JS validation I don't do, and only do it server side, as you might end up having to write two regexp queries that achieve the same results which can be difficult in different engines.

Comment: @Tom Gullen: I agree with you, but don't you think it might be useful to do this test also on client side?! Just to give a quick feedback to the user. Moroever porting a Javascript coded regex into a server side language like PHP it's not such a complex task.

Comment: If you are doing URL validation, this is the kind of ad hoc regexp jinxing I'm very opposed to. There's a full grammar specified for URLs (see RFC1738, e.g. at http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738) and so much "validation" code I've seen does not respect it. (It's even worse when it comes to email addresses.) In your case, for instance, why would you disallow sites on other ports than 80? In fact, you disallow even sites on default port 80 if explicitly specified (http://www.test.com:80), which is completely legal according to the RFC.

Comment: @Cumbayah: I would like to see your regex to validate email in form on client side, then! RFC2822 allow characters like quotes, curley brackets: ' { } and all sort of other crap in email part before the '@', are you going to allow those charters too in order to follow RFC2822. Well do it, and you are gonna only get tons of spam mail addresses that would not be handled by any mail server in the world.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to stick partially to your code a quick fix could simply use these:

`"^((https?\\://www\\.)|(www\\.))[A-Za-z0-9_\\-]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\%\\&\\?\\.\\=\\+]+$"` (accepts "http://www...." and "www...")

or

`"^(https?\\://www\\.)[A-Za-z0-9_\\-]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\%\\&\\?\\.\\=\\+]+$"` (accepts only "http://www...." and NOT "www...")

**Neither ones of the above accepts a domain without "www".**

Anyway your code (and also the adjusted code I placed above) is WRONG because they would both validate ok domains like these:

- http://www.dom_ain.com
- http://www.-domain.com
- http://www.subdomain.domain..gee%%%==all-crap-still-ok

Your regex would also accept a crap like this:

- cheers://www...

To validate **just the domain part** (*forcing www to be entered*) you can use this:

```
var URLReg = /^((https?\://wwww\.)|(www\.))([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9]|(\-[a-z0-9]))*\.)+[a-z]+$/i;
```

This one won't validate ok crap like:

- http://www.dom_ain.com
- http://www.-domain.com

BTW: It would validate also http://www.domain.com.com but this is not an error because a subdomain url could be like: http://www.subdomain.domain.com and it's valid!
And there is almost no way (or at least no operatively easy way) to **validate for proper domain tld** with a regex because you would have to **write inline into your regex all possible domain tlds ONE BY ONE** like this:

```
var URLReg = /^((https?\://wwww\.)|(www\.))([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9]|(\-[a-z0-9]))*\.)+(com|it|net|uk|de)$/i;
```

(this last one for instance would validate only domain ending with .com/.net/.de/.it/.co.uk)
**New tlds always come out**, so you would have to adjust you regex everytimne a new tld comes out, that's odd!

---

In order to validate also the remaining part of an url you could add the remainig part at the end of the regex:

`var URLReg = /^((https?\://wwww\.)|(www\.))([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9]|(\-[a-z0-9]))*\.)+[a-z]+(\/[a-z0-9_\-\%\&\?\.\=\+]*)*$/i`;

It's still not perfect because somone could enter:

http://www.domain.com/????hello

and it would validate ok, but now I'm tired, sorry! :)

Answer (score 0):

i use this expression - its the best i found:

```
^(https?://)?(([\w!~*'().&=+$%-]+: )?[\w!~*'().&=+$%-]+@)?(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([\w!~*'()-]+\.)*
([\w^-][\w-]{0,61})?[\w]\.[a-z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})?((/*)|(/+[\w!~*'().;?:
@&=+$,%#-]+)+/*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

See if

```
^[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-/]+\.com$
```

is what you want