# How to validate a complete and valid url using Regex

Tags: regex, validation

I have a URL validation method which works pretty well except that this url passes: "http://". I would like to ensure that the user has entered a complete url like: "http://www.stackoverflow.com".

Here is the pattern I'm currently using:

```
"^(https?://)"
+ "?(([0-9a-z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+: )?[0-9a-z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+@)?" //user@ 
+ @"(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" // IP- 199.194.52.184 
+ "|" // allows either IP or domain 
+ @"([0-9a-z_!~*'()-]+\.)*" // tertiary domain(s)- www. 
+ @"([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]{0,61})?[0-9a-z]\." // second level domain 
+ "[a-z]{2,6})" // first level domain- .com or .museum 
+ "(:[0-9]{1,4})?" // port number- :80 
+ "((/?)|" // a slash isn't required if there is no file name 
+ "(/[0-9a-z_!~*'().;?:@&=+$,%#-]+)+/?)$"
```

Any help to change the above to ensure that the user enters a complete and valid url would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a regex to validating a Url and support %20 and ()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068405/need-a-regex-to-validating-a-url-and-support-20-and)

Comment: Thanks, Daniel but the pattern given in that post passes 'http://'. I see that you can parse out all the constituent parts of the url but I'm hoping to use one regex pattern if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much a FAQ. You could simply try a search with [`[regex] +validate +url`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[regex]+%2Bvalidate+%2Burl) or just look at this answer: [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/256544)

Comment: Thanks, splash. After digging through your first link (the second one had the same problem I'm having) I found this post that did the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546203/validate-url-in-form-http-www-test-com (see Amir's answer). I did some preliminary testing and so far so good.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a urlparsing library? Let me list out some preexisting url parsing libraries for languages:

- Python: http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html
- Perl: http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI/Split.pm
- Ruby: http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html#M001444
- PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
- Java: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI(java.lang.String)
- C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Ask if I'm missing a language.

This way, you could first parse the uri, then check to make sure that it passes your own verification rules. Here's an example in Python:

```
url = urlparse.urlparse(user_url)
if not (url.scheme and url.path):
    raise ValueError("User did not enter a correct url!")
```

Since you said you were using C# on asp.net, here's an example (sorry, my c# knowledge is limited):

```
user_url = "http://myUrl/foo/bar";
Uri uri = new Uri(user_url);
if (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp && Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(user_url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) {
    Console.WriteLine("I have a valid URL!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I'm using c# (asp.net MVC 2). Most of my validation is done off the aspx page in classes.

Answer (score 0):

I use this regex. It works fine for me.

/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?://)?)(?:[-;:&=+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:/[+~%/.\w-*]*)?\??(?:[-+=&;%@.\w*]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/